# Is there a Ubuntu program that can convert cbz to jpg?

Tags: compatibility, convert

In order for me to read my comics on my PSP i need to convert them into jpg format. The official format of my comics is cbz, and i cant convert online because all the comics are about 7 gigabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your file name is `sample.cbz`, just:

`7z x sample.cbz -osample`

image files would be extracted into `sample` directory.

Comment: where is the "sample" directory?
do you mean it will extract the image into the same directory as the cbz?

Comment: Yes, the `-o` option sets the output directory. see `7z(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`.cbz` files are actually a zip file with jpgs or pngs in it.

Change the file extension from cbz to zip, uncompress the file with Archive Manager, then you'll be shown a bunch of image files!

Comment: there are 7 gigabytes worth of files, it will take forever to rename each, but thanks ill consider the fact that cbz is a compressed archive